# Wordpress dynamic sidebar without title

Tags: wordpress, function, wordpress-theming

I'd like to pull in a dynamic sidebar. I have 1 text item in the widget sidebar but I DON't want to pull in widget the title (just the body). Can anyone show me where WordPress is pulling in the Title?

e.g. At the moment I have...

```
// In my page template...
<div id='advert-header'>        
   <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'Header Advert' ); ?>
</div>

// In functions.php...
function twentyten_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Header Advert', 'twentyten' ),
        'id' => 'primary-widget-area',
        'description' => __( 'The primary widget area', 'twentyten' ),
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '',
        'before_title' => '',
        'after_title' => '',
    ) );
// etc.
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this (in `functions.php` within `register_sidebar`)

```
'before_title' => '<span class="hidden">',
'after_title' => '</span>',
```

And Css

```
.hidden{display:none;}
```

You can also try [this](http://askowen.info/2007/05/how-do-i-display-a-wordpress-widget-without-a-title/).

Comment: Hmmm I can't find that code in my WordPress.org installation. Maybe it's a core file?

Comment: If it's a core file, I would rather not touch it, but thanks for the suggestion. At the moment, the conclusion is to use your span class='hidden' suggestion, I was just wondering whether there was a more semantic way I could get control over it.

Comment: This is a dirty solution, you are hiding the title, not removing it.
filters should be applied to obtain a clean html code as result.

Comment: @NelloOllen, You are right because I've a f**king dirty mind :-)

Comment: I use a similar method, although I prefer to use HTML comments instead of CSS to hide the title: `'before_title' => '<!--', 'after_title'  => '-->'`. This has the benefit of being search-engine-transparent. In other words, the title text won't be counted by Google, et. al.

Answer (score 37):

Widget always have a filter applied on title name 'widget_title', use that.

```
add_filter('widget_title','my_widget_title'); 
function my_widget_title($t)
{

    return null;
}
```

**Thanks**

**-Shak**

Comment: This is the correct answer, let's see if we can't get the accepted answer modified...

Comment: Not sure if something changed with the later versions of WordPress, but I put this code in `functions.php` and the title field still shows in the dashboard widget. Or is this code supposed to do something else?

Comment: @J82 I just tested this code with a WordPress 4.9.8 version and it worked perfectly as expected.

Answer (score 6):

Those titles can be useful for CMS user, so in your `register_sidebar`, you can put sth. like I did in code below (works in Wordpress 5.0.3). Now widgets title is in html comment, it seems ok for me

```
  register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => esc_html__( 'Contact page widgets', 'xxx' ),
    'id'            => 'sidebar-3',
    'description'   => esc_html__( 'Add widgets here to appear on contact page.', 'xxx' ),
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<!-- ',
    'after_title'   => ' -->',
) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can make it even more simple by doing this in functions:

```
'before_title' => '<span style="display: none;">',
'after_title' => '</span>',
```

Answer (score 0):

couldn't you just do `display: none;` in the css for widget-title?

Comment: I could do this but I would rather not print the text out for SEO purposes really. I do realise it would be the easy way out though :-)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a title field for the widget you are using?
You could try just putting `&nbsp;` in there, so you get a space for the title.
Not the most elegant solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Please put this code in functions.php file.

```
add_filter( 'widget_title', 'remove_widget_title' );
function remove_widget_title( $widget_title ) {
    return $widget_title == '&nbsp;' ? '' : $widget_title;
}
```